# How to delete all sessions in database with a certain variable value (user ID)?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm storing sessions in a database and I want to delete all session rows for users when they log out as a security precaution (in case they're logged in on multiple computers).

My `sessions` table looks like this:

```
id                         | access              | data
mj6u4v5rs3hqbo18o5p3ip9h45   2014-08-14 02:47:02   user_id|i:1;fb_123412341234_user_id|s:11:"12341243";.....
```

If a user logs in on multiple computers, then there will be multiple rows in the database. The only way I can see to associate the rows with the user is the `user_id` variable in the `data` column.

My question is, how do I delete all rows associated with a particular user ID?

Here is the session class:

```
namespace app;

class Session {
    /** @var \PDO */
    private $db;

    function __construct(\PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;

        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, '_open'),
            array($this, '_close'),
            array($this, '_read'),
            array($this, '_write'),
            array($this, '_destroy'),
            array($this, '_gc')
        );

        session_start();
    }

    public function test() {
        return 'hey';
    }


    public function _open() {
        return true;
    }


    public function _close() {
        return true;
    }


    public function _read($id) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');
        makeQuery($stmt, array(':id' => $id));
        $sRow = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (!empty($sRow)) {
            return $sRow['data'];
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }


    public function _write($id, $data) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:id, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), :data)');
        makeQuery($stmt, array(':id' => $id, ':data' => $data));

        return true;
    }


    public function _destroy($id) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');
        makeQuery($stmt, array(':id' => $id));

        return true;
    }


    public function _gc($maxLifetimeTimestamp) {
        $maxLifetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $maxLifetimeTimestamp);

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE (UTC_TIMESTAMP() - access) > :maxLifetime'); // @todo test this to ensure math is correct
        makeQuery($stmt, array(':maxLifetime' => $maxLifetime));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"My question is, how do I delete all rows associated with a particular user ID?"* - Aren't you doing that with `DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, that delete's a particular row in the database. If a user is logged in on multiple computers, then there will be multiple rows in the database for them (each with unique IDs). So the row ID has nothing to do with the user ID, which is stored as session data.

Comment: @Nate ok, so what is the common denominator between those records? Find it, then use that to delete your data. *Edit:* just saw your post. Unstructured data will always make this kind of task tricky. You might have to create a custom condition for your delete using e.g. substring 0, 10 == `user_id|i:` and then the position of that until the semi-colon matches your user id

Comment: @scrowler The common denominator is the `user_id` value in the `data` column. However, the data in the `data` column is serialized, so I can't simply do a query for `delete from sessions where user_id = 1`. I might be able to do a fulltext search, but I thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my own solution. I modified my `sessions` table to add a `user_id` column, and then modified my `Session` class like this:

```
public function _write($id, $data) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (:id, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), :data, :userId)');
    makeQuery($stmt, array(':id' => $id, ':data' => $data, ':userId' => isset($_SESSION['user_id'])?$_SESSION['user_id']:null));

    return true;
}
```

Then, when logging the user out I use this code:

```
session_destroy();                                                   
unset($_SESSION);
setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time() - 48*3600, '/', null, null, true);
```

EDIT: then execute a query to delete all session rows from the database where `user_id` equals the user ID.

I'm still testing, but so far this seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

In short, with your current setup you cannot do what you want to accomplish.

All of your classes are setup to work off of the `id` in the session table, which correlates with a specific browser.

The only way I see you being able to do it is by creating a secondary script (either extend the class or create a completely different script) that will look through the session table, selecting every row and unserializing the `data` entity. However, I don't recommend this for a production, heavy volume site.

Can I ask why you need to delete all user sessions on logout?

Comment: `Can I ask why you need to delete all user sessions on logout?` Let's say someone logs on at the public library and then forgets to log out. What do they do? The only effective solution is to log out a user from all computers when they log out from one (i.e. by deleting all of the sessions for the user). Many websites, including StackOverflow take this approach.

Comment: Sure, but they also don't store their session data in the same manner as you. If you're truly worried about it, the quickest and safest way is to set your session timeout to a low threshold. Is that possible?

Comment: `Sure, but they also don't store their session data in the same manner as you.` How do they store it then?

Answer (score 0):

If `user_id` is always the very first token in the `data`, then you can do something like this:

```sql
DELETE FROM sessions WHERE SUBSTRING(data, 11, LOCATE(';', data) - 11) = {$user_id}
```

Here 11 is the length of "user_id|i:", so `substring` will return you the substring between the end of "user_id|i:" and the very first occurrence of the semicolon, which, if `user_id` always goes first, will be the user id.

If user_id is not necessarily the first token, then the function will be slightly harder (especially because your other variable, the fb111_user_id, has user_id as a substring), but still doable.